# How can I fix visible shading differences between parts of mesh?

Tags: modeling

[image]

Normals are fine but there is still a visible shading difference which is still there when exporting to a game engine, how can I fix this?

Comment: Hello please share your file: https://blend-exchange.com/

Comment: @moonboots It won't upload

Comment: or use another platform like workupload

Comment: If that is a single objecrt you could try selecting All in Edit mode then hitting M > Merge by Distance in case you have duplicate vertices.

Comment: @moonboots https://workupload.com/file/VHkP8w34x6F

Comment: @JohnEason It is a single object, and there are no duplicate verticies

Comment: The reason you couldn't use blend-exchange is because it was an .obj file not a native .blend one! I don't know how you created that file but it has horrible topology and internal faces where your shaded edges are showing. It can be improved somewhat by selecting the centre vert of the internal faces in Wireframe mode then Ctrl+ to expand the selection and X delete vertices but that won't get rid of all the topology problems.

Comment: @JohnEason Yeah, my first character model so terrible topology, but I'm fixing it now, is this better topology (apart from the temporary 6-sided shape)? https://imgur.com/a/aO1jQeZ

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to right click > *Shade Smooth*. Also you have inner faces as you see if you make some faces invisible, which creates a bad shading as Blender tries to smooth between the outer and the inner faces. To fix that, go into the *Select panel > Select All by Trait > Interior Faces* and press <kbd>X</kbd> > *Delete Faces*:

[image]

It is still not perfect because your topology is not perfect, but it's now better:

[image]

Comment: Thanks, I completely forgot about the interior faces I left, and yeah, topology is bad in quite a few places as this is my first character model